# My computer is not booting from CD/DVD/PenDrive

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb-flash-drive

Recently, I bought a computer which had **Windows 7 32bit** pre-installed.

I have a lot of apps to use, but unfortunately many of them work only in **Windows 64bit** OS.

I got Windows 8 64bit from my friend but when I try to install it from Pen Drive it won't boot from Pen Drive or from CD/DVD.

I have a Lenovo CPU, BIOS version is `5HKT50AUS`. My PC's processor is capable to upgrade to 64 bit.

Any idea what to do?

[image]

Comment: I can't see an image, I suggest you use another host for you image

Comment: Please upload your image using the "add image" button in the post editor, or at minimum host it on imgur. Thanks! :)

Comment: Now I have added new Link, check it out

Comment: What error message you get? Or it just sits there with a blinking or a steady cursor? Are you using Windows 8 retail DVD or a DVD that you created? How are you creating bootable pen drive & DVD if so?

Comment: It was my friend's CD/DVD and my another friend installed `Win 8` with same CD/DVD from which I am trying now OK

Comment: It was just created bootable from Windows